# what about (SWI) Prolog as NoSQL platform?

Tags: database, prolog, rdf, swi-prolog, plgi

I'd like to see (SWI)Prolog advertised as a NoSQL 'serious contender'.

(SWI)Prolog has awesome data bindings features, and lot of power - of course - to write logic against such big data.

With recent PLGI contribution, writing a sophisticated Gnome GUI has become really easy... What features are most expected from NoSQL fellows ? How does reactive CRUD of RDF sounds ?

I have already tested PLGI running several Gnome interfaces - standard like GtkClutter, or self written like graph_gtk (a graph editor, I'm porting this from [graph-gtk](https://github.com/CapelliC/graph-gtk), while learning native GIntrospection and GObject/GtkWidgets basics... I think I'm ready to bind Gtk - or generally GObjects - in a declarative way).

Comment: Maybe a NoSQL database should be able to 'store data on disk', then it should be able to be 'distributed', and query 'by pattern'. All databases must find them-self around the ACP-theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Does [library(persistency)](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=persistency) do what you want? It's single-user and doesn't scale across multiple nodes; adding multi-user should be fairly straight-forward (e.g., using [library(http/http_server)](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section(%27packages/http.html%27))) but scaling to multiple nodes would be some work (e.g., could use techniques from Erlang's mnesia, or a design similar to Google's Bigtable).

Another alternative would be to base the database off the [Prolog interface to an RDF database](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=semweb-rdf-db).